# ASP.NET Core MVC database does not add an object after redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 situations here.The first one happens when the page that I route to exists and the other one happens when the page does not exist.Kind of strange.

I try to add an object to my database in asp.net core but when I click the order button on my page it redirects me to the index page of the app(no big deal that can be solved), but my problem is that the object that I send in the POST request is not added to the database.

On the other hand if the page does not exist the object is added to the database(no problem) but I get an Internal Server Error which says "Index" could not be found in the folders that were used in searching for the page.My question is how can I still add the object to my database and still route to a page that I want to route to( for example a thank you for your purchase page).

I will now provide the code for the controller that I used and the endpoints code:

Endpoints:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/shopping")]
[ApiController]
public class SendItemsController : Controller
{
    private AppDbContext _db;
    
    public SendItemsController(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] ShoppingCart s)
    {
        await _db.ShoppingCarts.AddAsync(s);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
  
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="SendItems" asp-action="Save">



            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label id="clientName"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input id="inputName" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label id="clientAddress"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input id="inputAddress" type="text" />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label id="clientMail"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input id="inputMail" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-3 offset-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary " id="orderB">ORDER</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is the javascript that I use on the Cart page:

```
  var orderB = document.getElementById("orderB");
        orderB.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var inputName = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
            var inputAddress = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
            var inputMail = document.getElementById("inputMail").value;
            var auxArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < productsAux.length; i++) {
                if (productsAux[i]!="") {
                auxArray[i-1] = { "productName": productsAux[i].titlu, "productPrice": productsAux[i].pret, "quantity": localStorage.getItem(productsAux[i].titlu) };
                }
            }
            var shoppingCart = {
                productList: auxArray,
                clientName: inputName,
                clientAddress: inputAddress,
                clientMail: inputMail
            };
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(shoppingCart),
                url: "api/Shopping",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            })
        })
```

Comment: If it makes it to the redirect in this code, the object will have been saved. Sounds like you need to attach a debugger and verify if this method is even getting hit.

Comment: @mason it is not getting hit the first time but if I go to my cart page and hit the button again it gets hit.

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToPage` is used in Razor Page, while this is a MVC project, I think you need to use `RedirectToAction`.

> when I click the order button on my page it redirects me to the index page of the app

So, you want to trigger the `Save` action in `SendItemsController` by clicking the order button? What does the request look like, is the url right? Maybe you can show us the client side code.

I made a simple demo and tested with postman, you can have a reference.

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] ShoppingCart s)
{
    await _db.ShoppingCarts.AddAsync(s);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Thanks");
}

[HttpGet("Thanks")]
public IActionResult Thanks()
{
    return View();
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        var orderB = document.getElementById("orderB");
        orderB.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var inputName = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
            var inputAddress = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
            var inputMail = document.getElementById("inputMail").value;
            var auxArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < productsAux.length; i++) {
                if (productsAux[i] != "") {
                    auxArray[i - 1] = { "productName": productsAux[i].titlu, "productPrice": productsAux[i].pret, "quantity": localStorage.getItem(productsAux[i].titlu) };
                }
            }
            var shoppingCart = {
                productList: auxArray,
                clientName: inputName,
                clientAddress: inputAddress,
                clientMail: inputMail
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/Shopping",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(shoppingCart),

            })
        })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I tried to do what you said but now  I get a 415 "This page isn't working"

Comment: I added the html for the form that I use.On the other hand if I have the method  `public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }`  it adds the object to the database but it cannot find the Index page.Without this method I get the 415 that I was talking about.

Comment: Do I have to create another MapControllerRoute, because everything seems to be routed to the Index method.

Comment: Where is the thank you page placed in your example?

Comment: See my update, the thank you page is just returned by the Thanks action. If you don't know how to add a view, right click on the Thanks action, choose `Add View`.

Comment: I am also sending some JSON data regarding the products that the client bought.

Comment: @ballonDor Maybe you can show us the complete codes.

Comment: I have posted the javascript code that I use in order to create the JSON objects and post them.

Comment: If I use the FromForm I get null values in my Save method.

Comment: You need to prevent the default submission behavior of the form.Add this statement `e.preventDefault();` in your click function. See my update.

Comment: I added that line and now it adds the object to the database, but the app returns the cart page.It does not load the thank you page.Just freezes.

Comment: You can do the redirection in the ajax success function:`window.location.href="url";`

Comment: Still the same result.